# Display data before file upload in Shiny R

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I'm creating a simple Shiny app that allows the user to upload a csv file and plot various graphs with the uploaded data. I want to have some data preloaded into the app, so that users without any data can still graph things.

For now I'm just trying to print a table of either the uploaded file or the sample data.

I have the written the following code which doesn't work:

**server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$contents <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (!is.null(inFile)){
      renderTable({
        read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
             quote=input$quote)})
    }
    else{
      renderDataTable({
          diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]})
    }
   })
 })
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept = c(
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                 )
       ),
       tags$hr(),
       checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
       radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                     ','),
       radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                    '"')
     ),
    mainPanel(
              tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("contents"))
              )
             )
   )
))
```

I'm guessing I'm not assigning to output$contents correctly, but I really have no idea how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `renderTable` or `renderDataTable` from inside of `reactive()`. Factor it like this instead:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   tableData <- reactive({

     inFile <- input$file1

     if (!is.null(inFile)){
       read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
               quote=input$quote)
     }
     else {
       diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
     }
   })

   output$contents <- renderTable({
     tableData()
   })
 })
```